# How I use UNION ALL and LEFT JOIN in MYSQL DB

Tags: mysql

I have this problem that I can't solve
I have 3 tables like this:

| tbluser | tblproduct | tblerogation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | id | id |
| FullName | ProductName | UserId |
|  |  | ProductId1 |
|  |  | ProductId2 |
|  |  | ProductId3 |
|  |  | DateErogation |

The result I would like to get is this:

**Erogation History**

| id erogation | User FullName | ProductName (1,2,3) | DateErogation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

I'm currently stuck here:

```
SELECT * from (
SELECT id, UserId, DateErogation, ProductId1 as ProductId FROM tblerogation
UNION ALL
SELECT id, UserId, DateErogation, ProductId2 as ProductId FROM tblerogation
UNION ALL
SELECT id, UserId, DateErogation, ProductId3 as ProductId FROM tblerogation
) t
where MONTH(DataERogazione) = MONTH(now())
       and YEAR(DataErogazione) = YEAR(now()) // This for to filter result of current month
left join .....
left join .....
order by UserId;
```

any tips on how to get the results in the desired format?

Comment: It's not clear why you have sub query with union..please add sample data and desired outcome as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the product names to be grouped in one line, you can try this :

```
SELECT t.id as 'id erogation', u.FullName as 'User FullName', group_concat(p.ProductName) as ProductName, t.DateErogation
from (
  SELECT id, UserId, DateErogation, ProductId1 as ProductId FROM tblerogation
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, UserId, DateErogation, ProductId2 as ProductId FROM tblerogation
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, UserId, DateErogation, ProductId3 as ProductId FROM tblerogation
) t
inner join tbluser u on u.id = t.UserId
inner join tblproduct p on p.id = t.ProductId
group by t.id, u.FullName, t.DateErogation
order by t.id
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/wVARd_Im)

Comment: which logic follows the insertion of the 3 products after the union of the selects? I would like them to be extracted in the order product1 , 2 and 3 but the product id in my db is not always like this. It may happen that product1 has id 2 and product 2 has id 1 for example...

Comment: Not sure I undesrstand your requerements, but the group_concat supports its own order by clause, check here https://dbfiddle.uk/M7QDBTk4

Comment: according to the logic I use product1 corresponds to the CatId=7 of the tblproducts, (which I mistakenly did not specify in the initial question) product2 to the CatId=8 and productid3 to the CatId=9 . Here the pagination of the results must respect this condition... and not the product id maybe I should modify the query taking this detail into account

Comment: Then you can order by p.CatId in the group_concat()